# Project cannot be opened because its project type (.modelProj) is not supported

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Professional and when I'm trying to open a solution I get the following error:

**"Project cannot be opened because its project type (.modelProj) is not supported by this version of the application.
To open it, please use a version that supports this type of project."**

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need `Visual Studio Ultimate Edition` to use Modelling Projects.

Comment: Isn't there any possible way to do this with Visual Studio 2010 Professional?
Is this related to IIS Server?

Comment: The datasheets say that creating Modelling projects is for Ultimate only and the Premium Edition can read them. You have neither. I can't find anything about a relation to IIS.